# ng input tag add-on-enter does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, angularjs

add-on-enter only works on options generated from the auto-complete tag. If user were to enter text that are not included in the auto-complete tag, hitting enter will not reflect the exact text input by the user. Instead, it will select random options provided from the auto-complete tag. Here's my code:

```
<tags-input ng-model="itemoption[item.item_ID]" add-on-enter="true"   width="300" height="100"  >                                 

    <auto-complete highlight-matched-text="true" source="pinkid(item.item_ID)" min-length="1" load-on-down-arrow="true">
    </auto-complete>

</tags-input>
```

Comment: Why do you use add-on-enter directive ? I don't see it from the example page: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

Comment: I tried removing add-on-enter, but it does not work when <auto-complete> tag is included

Comment: Show your javascript code for the auto-complete source.